# draggable jquery UI with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Hi I have a problem with my page. I have added the script to content of page. I build this script on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LH8Rz/1/.

```
$("#timeline").draggable({
axis: "x",
containment: [-1549, 0, 0, 0]
});
```

On fiddle looks right and fine but on my page it's something wrong: http://truage-polska.pl/o-nas/ I try to fix that but I have no idea what's wrong. (Sorry for my bad english).

Comment: Oh you mean its cut off on the left side?

Comment: Probably, it is getting co-ordinates from document border or your main container.

Comment: Yes, is cut off on the left side, how can i fix it  ?